# polymer paper-date-picker increasing date by one day

Tags: javascript, polymer, momentjs, polymer-1.0

I am using paper-date-picker by BenDavis78 in my polymer element like this

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
 <template>
  <div>{{date}}</div>
  <iron-icon on-tap="_incrementDate" icon="chevron-right"  ></iron-icon>
  <iron-icon on-tap="_decrementDate" icon="chevron-left"  ></iron-icon>
  <paper-date-picker date={{date}}></paper-date-picker>
 </template>

   <script>
   Polymer({
     is: 'my-element'
   }),
   </script>

</dom-module>
```

the date is displaying fine but what i want to do is i need to provide two chevron-right and chevron-left icons so that i can increase/decrease the date by one day .

I have tried doing this

```
 _incrementDate: function(date){    
    var currentDate = date;
    var nextDay =  moment(currentDate).add(1, 'day');
    this.date = nextDay;
        },
```

but it's not seems to work.How can I make it to work.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in element. as `paper-calendar` has a logic where it checks if the date user is trying to set is current date or not before changing the style

Comment: is there any other ways?